# Making an Iterator with ES6

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This question has a lot of moving parts, but I'm going to start with the my first miscomprehension.

Context: An `Iterator` is defined as an Object that implements a `next()` method, which both of my examples down below have. The difference is that I'm creating an Object with a `next()` method differently. In my first example, I'm creating a function that returns an Object that contains a `next()` method. I then assign a variable to this function, so if I'm not mistaken, I am essentially making an Object on the fly with a predefined function.

```
var letters = ["a","b","c"];

function createIterator(array) {
    var i = 0;

    return {                //return an Object with a next() method
        next: function(){
            i < array.length ?    //if statement
            {value: array[i++], done: false}:
            {value: undefined, done: true};
         }
    }
}

var myIterator = createIterator(letters);
console.log(myIterator.next()) //{value: a, done: false}
console.log(myIterator.next()) //{value: b, done: false}
console.log(myIterator.next()) //{value: c, done: false}
console.log(myIterator.next()) //{value: undefined, done: true}
```

So, by putting the `createIterator` function inside a variable, `myIterator`, each time I run the `next()` function, I get the next element in the array I pass.

Okay, I thought. What if I just made the Object without the function?

```
var literal = {
    letters: ["a", "b", "c"],
    next: function(){        //same next function as before
        var i = 0;
        i < this.letters.length ? 
        {value: this.letters[i++], done: false}:
        {value: undefined, done: true};
         }
}

console.log(literal.next()) //{value: a, done: false}
console.log(literal.next()) //{value: a, done: false}
console.log(literal.next()) //{value: a, done: false}
console.log(literal.next()) //{value: a, done: false}
```

I think this is due to my misunderstanding of how I'm invoking the `next()` method with different ways of creating my Objects. It could be something with scope, but I'm really not entirely sure.

Comment: What's with that `var i = 0l` in the first snippet? Is this the actual code?

Comment: Your problem appears to be that you moved the `var i` declaration from an outer scope into the `next` function, where it now is initialised to `0` on every call. Instead of being incremented as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example `i` is captured in a closure so it works. In the second example `i` gets created new every time you call the function. You *could* make is a property of the object:

```js
var literal = {
    letters: ["a", "b", "c"],
    i: 0,
    next: function(){        //same next function as before
       return this.i < this.letters.length ? 
        {value: this.letters[this.i++], done: false}:
        {value: undefined, done: true};
         }
}

console.log(literal.next()) 
console.log(literal.next()) 
console.log(literal.next()) 
console.log(literal.next())
```

Of course you can also implement this in a way that it will work as an iterator in other contexts and is simpler:

```js
var G = {
    letters: ["a", "b", "c"],
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*(){      
       yield *this.letters
    }
}

// now the object works as an iterable:
console.log([...G])
// or
let iter = G[Symbol.iterator]()
console.log(iter.next()) 
console.log(iter.next()) 
console.log(iter.next()) 
console.log(iter.next())
```